# keybord interrupt event listener

Tags: python, events, listener, copy-paste

I have a problem with my script. i want do do an event listender for the whole script from beginning to the end.
if someone presses ctrl-c or something it should ignore, or end the scipt with an print.

I can show you my code if needed.

I tried signal and sys but I didnt know how to use it right

Comment: It will be better if you do so. Check [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for how to do it, that is, show an short example for people to work upon that you can adapt later, and show which code have you already tried.

Comment: I am just asking if there is a code which is listening the whole time the script is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach for ending the script with a print could be to wrap the whole script in a try/except block:

```
import sys

try:
    while 1:
        print 'To infinity and beyond!'
    # etc etc...

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Handling the keyboard interrupt...'
```

The interrupt still kills the script, but I would think this is desired behaviour for any user; personally I wouldn't recommend trying to override it.

Comment: +1, you made my laugh with 'To infinity and beyond!' loop hahaha.

Comment: Did this work out for you? Please do accept the answer if it did :)